# Can't return an object type in AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs, service

I need my service to return a json with info from server.

Code of service:

```
 app.service('Server', function () {

  this.fetch = function (data, token) {
     fetch('http://104.197.58.108:8080', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              data: data,
              token: token
            })
        })
          .then(function(response) { 
            return response.json()
          }).then(function(text) {
            if (text.success == false) {
              return false;
            } else {
              return text;             
            }          
          })
  }
})
```

Here's code from controller.

```
  $scope.data2 = '{"func":"materialSons","material":"0"}';
  console.log(Server.fetch($scope.data2, $rootScope.token));
  $scope.materialist = Server.fetch($scope.data2, $rootScope.token);
```

Request to server successes, but function returns undefined.
I also tried adding return statement before fetch() in service and that, what I got in log:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

Comment: Provide a callback function to the fetch method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fetch() method currently doesn't return anything. So it in fact returns `undefined`.

So you to add a return statement. And that will make the function return **a promise**. It can't return data, as a fetch is an asynchronous operation. So it returns a promise. That means that the caller must **not** do

```
$scope.materialist = Server.fetch($scope.data2, $rootScope.token);
```

It must instead do

```
Server.fetch($scope.data2, $rootScope.token).then(function(data) {
    $scope.materialist = data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.service('Server', function ($http) {

   this.getData = function(){
     var promise = $http({
     method : 'GET',
     url: 'http://104.197.58.108:8080'
   }).then(function(data){
      return data;
     }, function(error){
       return error;
    });
    return promise;
   }
```

Now inside your controller, call the service's method an assign the data to the scope variable and iterate/parse as necessary.

```
Server.getData().then(function(response){

$scope.fetchedData = response;

//Open the Sources tab by pressing in dev tools and see the format of the   response by setting debugger points.  
// or $scope.fetchedData and parse and assign the values accordingly.

});
```

I don't feel you will need to set headers object explicitly for JSON format. in case you do need to set headers in future, you can always do so by adding that in the $http method in pretty much the same format as you did. 
For more information on $http, refer [ngdocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)